# How does Perfect forward secrecy work in https?

Tags: tls

How does Perfect forward secrecy work in https?
How to check whether it is enabled or not?
Which big site actually use this? Paypal? Facebook? Amazon?

I have read this Wikipedia article, but I don't know how it is applied in ssl.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy
What are the weaknesses of this? How can it be broken?

Comment: How to check whether it is enabled or not? Which big site actually use this? Paypal? Facebook? Amazon?

Comment: gmail does use ECDHE_RSA

Comment: @CodesInChaos How do you check that?

Comment: @user27296: See question [How to check if the HTTPS connection is using perfect forward secrecy?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47912/how-to-check-if-the-https-connection-is-using-perfect-forward-secrecy)